# Issue : ViewPager with Imageview fetches same image from server on every scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview

I have used PagerAdapter to show images in viewpager. Problem I am facing is I am loading images from server, so when I scroll every time it fetches same image. I want to load image only once.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: I understand that you mean downloading it once and caching. If so, the easiest way is using Picasso, Glide or any other image loading library, that include caching support.